# CSS.paintWorklet working in PHCode/JSFiddle/CodePen but not on my site

Tags: css, css-houdini

I am trying to use paintWorklet to draw Squircle divs. I was just creating a basic test on phcode.dev, then actually went to use it on my own website. However, it did not work. So I also tried it on JSFiddle and CodePen, and it worked there too. How can I resolve this?

Chrome version:

> Version 118.0.5993.117 (Official Build) (64-bit)

**Images (result testing for paintWorklet):**
My Website:
[Website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RrRYX.png)
PHCode/JSFiddle/CodePen (All produce same result):
[Editors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bTXNH.png)

I did try using this polyfill:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/css-paint-polyfill
However, the results were not acceptable.

**Images:**
Expected:
[Expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DRZc4.png)
Result on my site:
[Real](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6IQtR.png)
Result with polyfill:
[Polyfill](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oPcJs.png)

JSFiddle with my code:
https://jsfiddle.net/7hyujv2g/

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-theme="light">
    <head>
        <title>Phoenix Editor for the web</title>
    </head>
 
    <body>

  <a class="btn-accent">button</a>
        
        <script>
          if ("paintWorklet" in CSS) {
            CSS.paintWorklet.addModule(
              "https://www.unpkg.com/css-houdini-squircle/squircle.min.js"
            );
          }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

css

```
:root {
    --font-size: 1.1rem;
    
    --btn-padding: 0.6em 0.8em;
    --btn-text-transform: uppercase;
    
    --default-squircle-smoothness: 0.45;
    --default-squircle-radius: 25px;
    
    --card-squircle-smoothness: 0.45;
    --card-squircle-radius: 15px;
}

html[data-theme="light"] {
    --color-el-1: #ffffff;
    --color-el-2: #f1f4f4;
    --color-accent: #5200ff;
    
    --color-text-main: #000000;
    --color-text-alt: var(--color-el-1);
}

.btn-accent {
    text-transform: var(--btn-text-transform);
    padding: var(--btn-padding);
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    transition: all 0.09s;
}

.btn-accent {
    background-color: var(--color-accent);
    color: var(--color-text-alt);
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The [PaintWorklet API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSS/paintWorklet_static) requires a [secure context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Secure_Contexts). You must serve your website through HTTPS (`localhost` is also considered *secure*).